# Race condition with simultaneous uploads in PHP

Tags: php, file-io, upload, race-condition

My PHP request handler looks like this:

```
// it's one file only, always
foreach($_FILES as $file){

  // error checks, move etc.
  if(!move_uploaded_file ...

  // assemble if the number of files match the total number of parts
  $numFiles = count(glob("{$tempDir}/*", GLOB_NOSORT));

  if($numFiles === $totalChunks){     // <- problem
    // assemble file
  }      

}
```

It appears that if two parts arrive at the same time that condition is fired twice.

Is there some way to upload a file in chunks, let's say 3 at a time, and avoid a race condition when assembling the file on the PHP side?

I was thinking to "sleep" for ~5 seconds inside a loop when the last part is uploaded (eg. #3 of 3). In the loop I'd keep doing the check until all other parts arrive. But what if the connection breaks and they don't? :)

Comment: Have you tried to lock (http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) the assembled file so no two script can attempt to write that file at the same even the condition breaks.

Comment: Thanks! Locking it with LOCK_EX seems to do the job, although I now have issues with some shell scripts that are supposed to do some file processing